# geom_col does not plot all data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have faced a weird behaviour of `geom_col` and it drives me crazy: basically it does not plot all the data points. When I add `geom_point()` I clearly see that they are not all represented with a bar.

MWE :

```
x = sample(1:2000, size = 600, replace = FALSE)
y = 1:600
ggplot(data.frame(x = x, y = y), aes(x,y)) + geom_col() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_col(position = "identity")` does not change anything

Comment: @Bankelal each point should have one associated bar. I have change the MWE so as to be more reproducible. I guess there is something with the range of `x`

Comment: This is not a problem with `geom_col`, but depends on you graphics device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually plotting all vertical lines, the problem is that it is too thin to show. If you zoom in you will see all the lines.

Try to make the width of the lines thicker, e.g.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = x, y = y), aes(x, y)) + geom_col(width = 3) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: uhmm, it works, but I think this is a very misleading behaviour of `geom_col`. What if the sequence becomes arbitrarily longer? It means that one can never be sure one sees all the samples

Comment: I also found it strange at first but it makes sense, you can not see arbitrarily thin lines on your monitor. The default `width` is just too thin.

Comment: they could overlap like `geom_point` and `geom_line` for instance